# Help me with a Chemistry Formula using ChemFig

Tags: chemfig

[image]

Please help me with this chemical formula using the ChemFig package. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the documentation first, [chemfig](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), [tikz](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Otherwise, it's something like

```
\schemestart
    \chemfig{H_{2}C(-O@{O1}H)-[:-90]HC(-[:-90]H_{2}C(-OH))-O-[0,1.5]@{Cu}Cu-[0,1.5]O-CH(-[:90]CH_{2}-[:180]OH)(-[:-90]CH_{2}-[:180]@{O2}OH)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw [->] (O1) edge (Cu);}
\chemmove{\draw [->] (O2) edge (Cu);}
```

*edit* - subscripts were unenveloped

Comment: I've tried compiling it, but there was a "missing { inserted" error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of vlg:

```
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_2|C(-@{O1}OH)-[:-90,,2,2]HC(-[:-90,,2,2]H_2|C(-OH))
    -O-[0,1.5]@{Cu}Cu-[0,1.5]O
    -CH(-[:90]CH_2-[:180]HO)(-[:-90]CH_2-[:180]H@{O2}O)}
\chemmove{\draw[->,shorten <= 2mm, shorten >= 2mm] (O1) -- (Cu);}
\chemmove{\draw[->,shorten <= 2mm, shorten >= 2mm] (O2) -- (Cu);}
\end{document}
```

gives me after compiling it twice:

[image: result]

It would be nice if you could give your question a more specific title so others know better what to expect, maybe something similar to "How to draw an arrow-shaped bond with ChemFig".